# Почему не работают сокеты Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, сокет

Пишу свое первое онлайн приложение. Весь вечер разбираюсь с сокетами: *создал сервер на телефоне и клиентское приложение на ноутбуке, но запрос не отправлялся с одного устройства на другое*. Смог отправить запрос только с того же устройства, на котором стоит сервер. Пытался осуществить отправку запроса с одного устройства на другое путем кода ниже. **Как я могу отправить запрос с одного устройства на другое?**

**Сервер на телефоне, ip-адрес телефона = 85.249.21.230 :**

```
import socket

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(("127.0.0.1",49674))
server.listen(4)

while True:
    user_socket, address = server.accept()
    print("Connected")
    user_socket.send("You are conn.".encode("utf-8"))
```

**Клиент на ноутбуке:**

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(("85.249.21.230",49674)) # Указал ip-адрес телефона
while True:
    data = sock.recv(2048)
    print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: А вы понимаете что значит 127.0.0.1 в строчке `server.bind(("127.0.0.1"`?

Comment: Не особо, вроде бы 127.0.0.1 = localhost?

Comment: Просто если 127.0.0.1 заменить на 85.249.21.230, то ничего не работает

Comment: Выдает [WinError 10049] Требуемый адрес для своего контекста неверен

Comment: С чего вы взяли что `85.249.21.230` это адрес телефона?

Comment: В гугле посмотрел

Comment: Ох… вам предстоит много узнать про устройство сети…

Comment: Я понимаю, что мне совершенно неясен принцип работы сокетов, но в чем моя ошибка?

Comment: В том, что у вашего телефона адрес не 85.249.21.230. И это касается не сокетов, а принципов работы сети как таковой. Скорее всего ваш провайдер не дает вам реальный ip и на этом адресе за NAT у него множество абонентов. К таким адресам снаружи подключаться в принципе нельзя. А гугл вам показывает только с какого адреса вы пришли к нему

Comment: Но принцип верен, т.е. если я смог бы узнать реальный ip телефона, то все заработало бы?

Comment: Да, если бы у телефона этот реальный ip вообще был, то все бы работало

Comment: Можно ли в интернете купить какой-нибудь левый ip и использовать его как сервер?

Comment: Зачем же левый ip, можно взять VPS, т.е. полноценный сервер

Comment: Спасибо вам большое! Вы даже не представляете, как выручили! В таком случае последую вашему совету

Comment: Ну в целом для экспериментов достаточно подключить телефон и компьютер к одной домашней сети. Обычно в них нет запрета на общение между устройствами

Comment: Я пытался так сделать, но такой вариант меня не устраивает