# Не работает сервер на python

Tags: python, сокет

У меня есть 2 файла 1-й:
server.py

```
import os
os.system("title Taplik_oc Server")

from rich.console import Console
console = Console()

console.print("Запуск сервера...")
console.print("[green]Сервер успешно запущен.[/green]")
print("Ожидание входящих отзывов...")
import socket
# Определить сокет 
fwq= socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
# Привязка адреса и порта
fwq.bind(('127.0.0.1',50000))
# Слушайте до 5 соединений
fwq.listen(5)
#accept получит запрошенный адрес, порт и вернет новый сокет,
# Если на сервере три клиентских соединения, то есть четыре сокета, один из которых является только что созданным сокетом
conn,addr=fwq.accept()  
# Напишите цикл, чтобы облегчить чат
while 1:
    # Размер получаемой информации 1024 байта
    client_msg=conn.recv(1024)
    # Полученная информация закодирована и должна быть расшифрована здесь
    recvmsg=client_msg.decode('utf-8')
    # Суждение, если вход "q", затем выйдите из цикла и закройте сокет
    if recvmsg=='q':
        break
    # Если нет, распечатайте декодированную информацию
    print('Отзыв:'+recvmsg)
    # Введите то, что сервер хочет ответить
    replymsg=input('Обнаружен отзыв! Введите ответ ')
    if replymsg == "/b /e":
        # Используйте соответствующий сокет для отправки этого ответного сообщения
        conn.send(replymsg.encode('utf-8')) #Сообщение
        # Закройте первый сокет
        fwq.close()
        # Закрыть вновь созданный сокет
        conn.close()
        exit()
    else:    
        # Используйте соответствующий сокет для отправки этого ответного сообщения
        conn.send(replymsg.encode('utf-8')) #Сообщение
        # Закройте первый сокет
        fwq.close()
        # Закрыть вновь созданный сокет
        conn.close()
```

2-й os.py (часть кода с ошибкой)

```
def feedback():
    # Создать сокет
    client=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client.connect(('127.0.0.1',50000)) 
    while 1:
        # Введите контент, который вы хотите отправить
        send_msg=input("Введите отзыв: ")
        print("[БОТ]: Спасибо за отзыв ожидайте ответа в течении 1-3 минут.")
        # Кодировать последние отправленные сообщения
        client.send(send_msg.encode('utf-8')) 
        # Это должно судить об окончании цикла while, иначе он станет бесконечным циклом
        if send_msg=='q':
            break
        # Декодировать полученное сообщение (самое принятое сообщение - 1024 байта)
        back_msg=client.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
        # Распечатать полученное сообщение
        if back_msg == "/b":
            my_file = open("Blocked.txt", "w+")
            my_file.write("qs-s-s-qsfd-ds-00x7")
            my_file.close()
        elif back_msg == "/b /e":
            my_file = open("Blocked.txt", "w+")
            my_file.write("qs-s-s-qsfd-ds-00x7")
            my_file.close()
            print("Через 2 секунды будет выполнен выход по решению администрации.") 
            time.sleep(2)
            exit()   
        else:
            print(back_msg)
    # Закрыть созданный сокет
    client.close()
```

Так вот когда я запускаю сервер и клиента то всё работает. Но когда кто-то другой запускает с другого пк то выдаёт ошибку

```
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение
```

Как исправить эту ошибку?
Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: IP и порты соответствуют на другой машине. Как организована сеть?

Comment: `fwq.bind(('127.0.0.1',50000))` А чего вы ещё хотели, если ваш сервер слушает только localhost?

Comment: @GrAnd А как сделать что-бы слушался всего что надо для сервера?

Comment: `fwq.bind(('', 50000))` будет слушать всё. Об этом написано в [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html#creating-a-socket).

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1368837/Почему-не-работают-сокеты-python

куча таких вопросов без ответов, так что и дубликат не поставить))